# Does ngrx preserve action order?

Tags: ngrx

If multiple actions are dispatched on the same store:

```
store.dispatch(new SomeAction());
store.dispatch(new SomeOtherAction());
```

Are the reducers guaranteed to process these actions in the same order they were dispatched?

Comment: Yes. If you'd like to read more about ngrx/store, I've written an article [here](https://indepth.dev/understanding-the-magic-behind-ngrx-store/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they are.
But keep in mind that effects are async, for example if `SomeAction` is handled by `EffectA` and it dispatches another action `EffectAction`, that `SomeOtherAction` will probably be handled before `EffectAction`.